# How to get JSTL Tag like ${Some} in jsp page but Some is not a value

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, jstl

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%><%@ page contentType="text/xml" %><%@ page isELIgnored="false" %><c:out value='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>' escapeXml="false"/>
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
    <section name="dialplan" description="RE Dial Plan For FreeSwitch">
        <context name="default">
          <domain name="192.168.1.2" alias="true">
             <groups>
              <group name="default">
                 <users>
                   <c:forEach items="${extension}" var="extension">
                     <user id="${extension.username}">
                        <params>
                            <param name="dial-string" value="{presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}${sofia_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})} "/>
                        </params>
                        <variables>
                           <variable name="password" value="${extension.password}"/>
                           <variable name="user_context" value="default"/>
                            <variable name="effective_caller_id_name" value="${extension.callerIdName}"/>
                            <variable name="effective_caller_id_number" value="${extension.callerIdNumber}"/>
                        </variables>
                     </user>
                   </c:forEach>
                 </users> 
              </group>
            </groups>
         </domain>
       </context>
    </section>
</document>
```

And I want a response like

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
<section name="directory">
<domain name="192.168.1.2" alias="true">
<groups>
<group name="default">
<users>
<user id="2002">
      <params>
            <param name="dial-string" value="
```

> {presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}
>                           ${sofia_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})} "/>

```
           </params>
    <variables>
    <variable name="password" value="Pwd12345"/>
    <variable name="user_context" value="default"/>
    <variable name="effective_caller_id_name" value="2002"/>
    <variable name="effective_caller_id_number" value="2002"/>
    </variables>
    </user>
    </users>
    </group>
    </groups>
    </domain>
    </section>
    </document>
```

BUT here I am getting Error on line  where we print a JSTL TAG as a response. How can I remove it? Any one can suggest me?

Comment: and what response you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use string

```
<param name="dial-string" value='"presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}${sofia_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})"' />
```

Comment: Thanks dear for healp..but your code not Solved it. i get a solution like....                                                                                           `<params><%! String s1="{presence_id=${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain}}${sofia_contact(${dialed_user}@${dialed_domain})}"; %>
                   <param name="dial-string" value="<%=s1%>"/>
                  </params>`